# is there a way to update go packages and ignore errors?

Tags: go

Here's the scenario:

- in package `myPackage` I make a breaking change. No worries, it's private, nobody cares
- in project `myProject` I would like to use the new `myPackage` version.
- running `go get -u ./...` in `myProject` will not update the package, since go will find errors (due to the breaking changes).

I can see how this is a good idea, but in this very case I would like go to force the update, break everything, so I can follow the compiler errors until my code is finally ready.

Is there  any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Is the `myPackage` present at a specific remote branch? and its present already in the `myProject` go.mod?

Comment: it is present in go.mod, in it's previous version (before breaking change), and the new code is now available on master (I didn't use semantic versionning)

Comment: In that case, you can force a update as `go mod edit -require=<path>/<package>@latest` and do a `go mod vendor`

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for ! Make it an answer if you like !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-d` flag causes `go get` to download the requested packages but not build them. (The `-d` flag is [planned to be the default behavior](https://golang.org/issue/43684) of `go get` starting with Go 1.18.)

`go get -d -u ./...` should perform the update you intend.